# How is browsing from a virtual machine/virtual box preventing fingerprinting or tracking?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, privacy, fingerprinting

is it increasing your internet security in terms of privacy/tracking/fingerprinting, if you are surfing with your web browser in a virtual machine enviroinment (virtual box + vpn)? Instead of surfing from your normal windows operating system...

Or is a virtual machine not helping you in fingerprinting cases? I just want to understand if you can use a virtual machine as a additional privacy tool and if yes, on what aspects would it have an impact (ip address, virus infections, fingerprinting, etc.)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you're hosting a VM on your local machine, it may share the same IP as your host, as far as the outside world is concerned. Most hypervisors allow you to change how it obtains an IP address, but in typical configs it will only change on your local network, which is probably NATed behind a single address provided by your ISP. A VPN is a good way to change that, and you can configure that either inside or outside the VM, though ideally you'd no want to be sharing an IP with your host system.

Using a VM can help against fingerprinting because you can be running a different browser in a different OS in your VM than on your host system - but that instance itself can be tracked/fingerprinted, so it may be a good idea to rotate through a series of different configurations (or use a browser plugin that randomises some settings, such as reported browser version, OS, installed fonts, etc), and to throw away changes in your VM each time you use it, which will eliminate even the hardest of "supercookies" that might try to track you.

Unless your hypervisor is compromised (this has happened in the past, but it's rare), the VM itself will provide good protection from malware - for example Windows malware will have no effect on a Linux VM, and vice versa - and any malware that does infect your VM is contained by the sandbox that the VM provides - and you can simply reset it to return to a known-clean state, or throw it away and start again.